# 2 variables should influence my calculations, but the calculations can't get past an if

Tags: python

I want `weave` and `length` to determine 2 numbers in my equations.  The last number in the equation is preset based on the `weave` entered.

Here is the code

```
# I want users to enter the weave and the functions to take that weeave 
# and calculate with with entered length and the predefined thickness of 
# the weave. 

weave = "hex nut"  # The weave determines the thickness of the braclet.
length = 6      # length determins that circumfrence of the wrist.
if weave == "cobra" or "fishtale" or "dragon tounge" or "braid":
    print(f"Your "  + (weave) + " braclet length inluding the buckle should be:")
    print(f"{length + .5 + (3.1459*.3125)}"+ " inches.") # length + .5 + (3.1459*.3125) 
                                                         # .3125 is the thickness of any the 
                                                         # weaves in the if statment

elif weave == "extreme weave":
    print(f"Your "  + (weave) + " braclet length inluding the buckle should be:")
    print(f"{length + .5 + (3.1459*.25)}"+ " inches.")

elif weave == "hex nut":
    print(f"Your "  + (weave) + " braclet length inluding the buckle should be:")
    print(f"{length + .5 + (3.1459*.44)}"+ " inches.")
    
elif weave == "blaze bar":
    print(f"Your "  + (weave) + " braclet length inluding the buckle should be:")
    print(f"{length + .5 + (3.1459*.38)}"+ " inches.")

elif weave == "king cobra or solomons dragon":
    print(f"Your "  + (weave) + " braclet length inluding the buckle should be:")
    print(f"{length + .5 + (3.1459*.5)}"+ " inches.")

else:
    print("Sorry, at this time " + (weave) + " is not in our Script.  Select another weave for your braclet.")
    print("Please contact Eric at elaunderville@gmail.com or ericlaunderville.tech")
```

I can get the `weave` to print but the calculations stop at the `if` statement

Comment: The problem is the line `if weave == "cobra" or "fishtale" or "dragon tounge" or "braid":`. See the duplicate question for why.

Comment: Please see [Why does `a == b or c or d` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true)

Comment: try `if weave in [ "cobra" , "fishtale" , "dragon tongue",  "braid"]:`